# Swipe between webviews in Xamarin

Tags: c#, webview, xamarin, cross-platform, swipe-gesture

Anyone knows a way to swipe between `WebView`s using C# in `Xamarin`?

I have a list of static URLs that I want to swipe between like cards (Tinder like). Each `WebView` will load one URL and the user will be able to swipe between them like Carousel.

Best practice ways will help a lot.

Comment: Could this sample help you https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/ActionBarViewPager ?

Comment: I need only to swipe between webview.